# Remote Control of iOS Tablets: Seeking Solutions Beyond Jailbreaking (2023)

Tags: ios, ipad, remote-desktop, remote-control

I have a very specific use case. In my company, we have agents who need to go out into the field and they have tablets. They are often quite far away geographically. Normally, we use Android tablets, but recently, we decided to switch to Apple. We use our own applications and we install them using SOTI and Soti mobicontrol. However, the issue we've encountered is that we realized it's impossible to remotely control their tablets, which is very frustrating because sometimes we need administrative access to our applications and we're no longer able to do it. Despite my efforts to search, I come across old questions on this topic, but as of 2023, is there still no solution to remotely control an iOS tablet without having to jailbreak it?

Answer (score 1):

There are several commercial options available for remotely controlling iPads *within* those custom applications that you mention.

A general remote control of the entire iPad over cellular connection is not currently possible without extra hardware.

However, you can get general remote *viewing* of the entire iPad. There are several commercial options for that that. You will be able to see everything that happens on the iPad's display, including inside apps such as "Settings" - but you cannot control it remotely.

A commercial option could for example be TeamView for iOS or AnyDesk for iOS.

Comment: what do you mean by extra hardware ?

Comment: @snoobdogg I mean a device external to the iPad itself (something with a bit of computing power and USB).

Comment: it does exists ?  where i can found something like that ?

Comment: A Mac would qualify for example… 

Comment: ahh yes in that sens ^^